# Android Studio 4.0 Color Previews

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, preview

[image: Android Studio 4.0]

I upgraded android studio for 4.0 today. Color previews enabled but not showing in gutter line. Any solution?

Comment: That's interesting -- they are showing up for me. If you create a new scrap project, do the gutter icons show up in that project?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this method can help you.
Open the settings page(Ctrl + Alt + S), search "Gutter Icons". 
check the checkbox of "show gutter icons".
there you can customized the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of using custom attr in theme in manifest. Once I replaced attr with style the colores showed up again.